# Dockerfile: How to replace a placeholder in environment variable with build-arg's?

Tags: bash, docker, sed, terminal, dockerfile

I have a web application which I want to run on Docker for testing purposes.
The application uses a database as storage and the configuration for the database is maintained in an environment variable (JSON).
Below you can see the env variable definition in my Dockerfile (see also my approaches below)

```
ENV CONFIG '{  \
  "credentials":{    \
      "hostname": "172.17.0.5",  \
      "password": "PWD", \
      "port": "1234", \
      "username": "${USER}"  \
     },  \
     "name":"database",  \
     "tags":[]  \
  },  \
...
```

If I hardcode all parameters for the database everything is working but I don't want to change my Dockerfile only because the IP address of the database has changed.
Therefore I want to use Docker build-args.
I already tried two approaches:

1. Directly reference the variable (see line with "${USER}")
2. Replace a placeholder like "PWD" with the following command `RUN CONFIG=$(echo $CONFIG | sed 's/PWD/'$db_pwd'/g')`

The first approach results in no replacement so ${USER} is ${USER}. The second approach seems to work (at least in terminal) but it seems like the variable assignment is not working.

Do you have any idea how I can make this work? Feel free to suggest other approaches. I just don't want to have hardcoded parameters in my Dockerfile.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Variable expansion can only work in double-quoted strings. This is working:

```
ENV CONFIG "{  \
  \"credentials\":{    \
      \"hostname\": \"172.17.0.5\",  \
      \"password\": \"PWD\", \
      \"port\": \"1234\", \
      \"username\": \"${USER}\"  \
     },  \
     \"name\":\"database\",  \
     \"tags\":[]  \
  }"
```

A simple example:

```
FROM alpine

ENV USER foo
ENV CONFIG "{  \
  \"credentials\":{    \
      \"hostname\": \"172.17.0.5\",  \
      \"password\": \"PWD\", \
      \"port\": \"1234\", \
      \"username\": \"${USER}\"  \
     },  \
     \"name\":\"database\",  \
     \"tags\":[]  \
  }"

ENTRYPOINT env | sort
```

_

```
$ docker build -t test .
$ docker run -it --rm test
CONFIG={    "credentials":{          "hostname": "172.17.0.5",        "password": "PWD",       "port": "1234",       "username": "foo"       },       "name":"database",       "tags":[]    }
HOME=/root
HOSTNAME=43d29bd12bc5
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
PWD=/
SHLVL=1
TERM=xterm
USER=foo
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately your solution does not work...
When I check the config variable after the container creation the field looks the following ´"username": \"${USER}\"´

Comment: Thanks, I had a small typo in it therefore it wasn't working when I first tried your solution.

Your solution works, thank you!